# Angular2 Heroes example doubles POST when combined with node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular2-http

I have set up the Heroes example up to step 10. Http Client. I've run the example to, which runs fine. Now, I'm replacing the "dummy" server with a Node.JS server on port 3002, replacing the _HeroesURL to "http:/localhost:3002/hero". The GET since then runs fine, the POST (attached to addHero) gets called twice into an error?

My Node.js server:

```
var dbHeroes = [
{"id": 11, "name": "Mr. Nice"},
{"id": 12, "name": "Narco"},
{"id": 13, "name": "Bombasto"},
{"id": 14, "name": "Celeritas"},
{"id": 15, "name": "Magneta"},
{"id": 16, "name": "RubberMan"},
{"id": 17, "name": "Dynama"},
{"id": 18, "name": "Dr IQ"},
{"id": 19, "name": "Magma"},
{"id": 20, "name": "Tornado"}]

var id = 21;

var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  // approve XHR-requests
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-type");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method","GET POST");

  // set up some routes
  switch (req.url) {
     case "/hero":
     switch (req.method) {
        case "GET":
        // getting heroes
        res.writeHead(200, "OK", {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        res.write(JSON.stringify(dbHeroes));
        res.end();
        break;

      case "OPTIONS":
        // pre-flight request (XHR)
        res.writeHead(200, "OK", {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
      res.end('Allow: GET POST');
      break;

    case "POST":
      var body = '';

      // get a chunk of the body
      req.on("data", function(chunk) {
          body += chunk;
      })

      // body finished
      req.on("end", function () {
        var newHero = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log("recieved hero: " + body);

        newHero.id = id++;
        console.log("hero is now:" + JSON.stringify(newHero));

        dbHeroes.push(newHero);

        res.writeHead(200, "OK", {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        res.write(JSON.stringify(newHero));
        res.end();
      })
      break;

      default:
        console.log(" [501] Request: unknown method " + req.method);
        res.writeHead(501, "Not implemented", {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.end('<html><head><title>501 - Not implemented</title></head><body><h1>Not implemented!</h1></body></html>');
        break;
  }
  break;

default:
  // return not found on all other routes
  res.writeHead(404, "Not found", {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end("<html><head>404 Not Found</head>
  <body><h1>Not Found</h1>The requested url was not found.</body>
  </html>");
  };}).listen(3002); // listen on tcp port 3002 (all interfaces)
```

Comment: Where is client side code?

Comment: It is exactly the same as the Heroes example at angular.io: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#

Comment: The problem seems to be browser-specific. On Firefox, the POST runs twice. This morning, i tried Chrome, which runs the POST once, and then runs into an error:  `angular2.dev.js:23524 EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in [
    {{hero.name}}
   in HeroListComponent@2:31]
angular2.dev.js:23514 EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in [
    {{hero.name}}
   in HeroListComponent@2:31]BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23514BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @ angular2.dev.js:23525ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js:1145(anonymous function

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: BrowserSync found two instances of Angular2-app running, and sync'd the click on the button on both instances. Fixed by turning this "feature" off....